# How do you use exe python package installer with Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I have a .exe installer for a python package that I want to use on one of my Anaconda environments. When I click on the .exe the installer want me to "Select python installation to use" and the python installation for my Anaconda environment doesn't appear. I tried messing around with PATH variables and it didn't work.

Comment: What did you tried? What errors do you get?

Comment: When it asks me to chose a python version to install it for, the python version for my anaconda environment did not appear on the list.